# Plotting datapoints and line at the same time with Matplotlib Widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I'm trying to plot both a line and data points on the same axis in Matplotlib. When I try to plot the line first, the data points get cleared and the same is true when I try to plot the data points first. Here is the minimal code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import ui_sof_test  #Gui File
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

class Gui(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui_sof_test.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):        
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.call_test()
    def call_test(self):
        x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        y = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000]
        self.plot_test(x,y)
    def plot_test(self, x, y):        
        ax1 = self.mplwidget.axes
        fig = self.mplwidget.figure #Add a figure 
        ax1.plot(x, y, 'k', linestyle = "solid", linewidth = 1)
        ax1.plot(x, y, "ro")        
        #Log scale
        ax1.set_xscale('log')
        ax1.set_yscale('log')
        #format tick labels
        ax1.axis([1, 20, 100, 100000])
        #set Limits        

        #Gridlines
        #Plot y axis minor tick marks

        minorLocatory = AutoMinorLocator()
        ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocatory)
        ax1.tick_params(which='both', width= 0.5)
        ax1.tick_params(which='major', length=7)
        ax1.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='k')
        ax1.minorticks_on()
        #Make Border of Chart White
        fig.set_facecolor('white')
        #Plot Grid        
        ax1.grid(b=True, which='both', color='k', linestyle='-')    

        #Draw Chart
        fig.canvas.update()
        fig.canvas.draw()    

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  # A new instance of QApplication
    form = Gui()  # We set the form to be our ExampleApp (design)
    form.show()  # Show the form
    app.exec_()  # and execute the. app

if __name__ == '__main__':  # if we're running file directly and not importing it
    main()  # run the main function
 `
```

Here is python code created from the PYQT4 UI file. Just save it as ui_sof_test.py:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(1441, 705)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1111, 671))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.mplwidget = MatplotlibWidget(self.tab)
        self.mplwidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 761, 461))
        self.mplwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mplwidget"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1441, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Motor Tester", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Test", None))

from matplotlibwidget import MatplotlibWidget
```

Comment: I'm actually plotting the same data. I am just overlaying data points over the line.

Comment: I also just tried without log scale. I am getting the same result.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I believe my question meets the criteria. Desired behavior: Plot both data points and line, Specific Problem: Will plot one or the other but not both. Also, code is pretty short. I appreciate your answer but my code still doesn't produce both plots. Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've updated the code as I am still having the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the first plot gets removed from the axes upon plotting the second one.
A workaround would be to add the first plot manually after plotting the second.

```
line, = ax1.plot(x, y, 'k', linestyle = "solid", linewidth = 1)
line2, = ax1.plot(x, y, marker="o", color="red", ls="")  
ax1.add_artist(line)
```

Because in principle the plotting procedure works fine (as shown below), the reason needs to be the use of `MatplotlibWidget`, for which I'm uncertain about what it actually does.

But if we replace it by

```
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
self.mplwidget = FigureCanvas(fig)
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.mplwidget, _fromUtf8(""))
```

where we have imported

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

and later use

```
ax1 = self.mplwidget.figure.axes[0]
```

the plot is shown as expected. 
So you may just cease to use `MatplotlibWidget`, if it's causing such strange problems.

---

Minimal example that shows that the principle plotting works as expected:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
import numpy as np

class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mplwidget = self
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

    def plot_test(self, x, y):
        ax1 = self.mplwidget.axes
        fig = self.mplwidget.figure #Add a figure 
        ax1.plot(x, y, 'k', linestyle = "solid", linewidth = 1)
        ax1.plot(x, y, "ro")        
        #Log scale
        ax1.set_xscale('log')
        ax1.set_yscale('log')
        #format tick labels
        ax1.axis([1, 20, 100, 100000])
        #set Limits        

        #Gridlines
        #Plot y axis minor tick marks
        minorLocatory = AutoMinorLocator()
        ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocatory)
        ax1.tick_params(which='both', width= 0.5)
        ax1.tick_params(which='major', length=7)
        ax1.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='k')
        ax1.minorticks_on()
        #Make Border of Chart White
        fig.set_facecolor('white')
        #Plot Grid        
        ax1.grid(b=True, which='both', color='k', linestyle='-')         
        #Draw Chart
        fig.canvas.update()
        fig.canvas.draw()

x, y = np.linspace(1,20), np.logspace(2, 5)

c = C()
c.plot_test(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]